# Grouping from multiple arrays and find sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these documents.

```
[
    {
        _id: 'a1',
        sales: [
            {
                amont: 12,
                servicer_id: 'A',
            },
            {
                amont: 10,
                servicer_id: 'B',
            },
        ],
        service: [
            {
                amont: 25,
                servicer_id: 'A',
            },
            {
                amont: 20,
                servicer_id: 'B',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        _id: 'a2',
        sales: [
            {
                amont: 10,
                servicer_id: 'A',
            },
            {
                amont: 20,
                servicer_id: 'B',
            },
        ],
        service: [
            {
                amont: 15,
                servicer_id: 'A',
            },
            {
                amont: 10,
                servicer_id: 'B',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

From the above document, I want to find the following.

1.Number of the service done by both servicer A and B.

2.Number of the sales done by both servicer A and B.

3.Total service amount of servicer A and B.

4.Total sales amount of servicer A and B.

Expected Output

```
[
    {
        servicer: 'A',
        services: 2,
        sales: 2,
        totalSale: 22,
        totalService: 40,
    },
    {
        servicer: 'B',
        services: 2,
        sales: 2,
        totalSale: 30,
        totalService: 30,
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach for this is quite simple, we're going to `$group` by the service id, and use `$sum` to calculate all the needed values, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$service",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        serviceId: "$service.servicer_id",
        docId: "$_id"
      },
      services: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      sales: {
        $first: "$sales"
      },
      totalService: {
        $sum: "$service.amont"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      serviceSales: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sales",
          as: "sale",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$sale.servicer_id",
              "$_id.serviceId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.serviceId",
      services: {
        $sum: "$services"
      },
      sales: {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$serviceSales"
        }
      },
      totalService: {
        $sum: "$totalService"
      },
      totalSale: {
        $sum: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$serviceSales",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this.amont"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j_JP1O52mFZ)

Comment: I have checked the above answer. But I got the wrong amount when I  add one more object to the service array. for more https://mongoplayground.net/p/5pNK2gA6lwL

@Tom Slabbaert

Comment: which field is the problem exactly? one of the `$sum` operators is probably not the logic you want.

Comment: Could you please check the link https://mongoplayground.net/p/5pNK2gA6lwL. The no. of sales is wrong for servicer B. Actually, Servicer A having only 2 sales. These error occurs  when I add one more object to servicer array

Comment: Ok it appears i misunderstood the question, here is a fix that should work:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/j_JP1O52mFZ
i will also edit my answer. notice this is under the assumption that there can't be a sale of a service without that service being in that same array.